# sql select pivot multiple tables

Tags: sql, pivot, multiple-tables

I have seen similar questions, but none quite hit the mark for what I am trying to do.

3 tables: product, plan, performance.

The performance table, aside from serving a purpose, represents a many-to-many relationship between the two other tables.

Let's call the linking fields:

```
performance.PlanID = plan.PlanID
performance.ProductID = product.ProductID
```

There are 3 fields of interest for this:

```
product.ProductName
plan.Status (Live or Pending)
performance.Capacity
```

I am looking to write a select query with the below results:

```
ProductName
LiveCapacity
PendingCapacity
```

I tried a pivot with the needed inner joins in the FROM (SELECT...) part of the query, but I cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pivot example.

```
SELECT 
    t.ProductName,
    [Live] AS LiveCapacity,
    [Pending] AS PendingCapacity
FROM 
(
    SELECT  product.ProductName,
          performance.Capacity,
          plan.Status 
    FROM    product 
          JOIN performance ON performance.ProductID = product.ProductID
          JOIN plan ON performance.PlanID = plan.PlanID
) t
PIVOT (
    SUM(Capacity)
    FOR Status IN ([Live],[Pending])
) p
```

Non-Pivot example

```
SELECT  product.ProductName,
        SUM(CASE WHEN plan.Status = 'Live' THEN performance.Capacity END) as LiveCapacity,
        SUM(CASE WHEN plan.Status = 'Pending' THEN performance.Capacity END) as PendingCapacity
FROM    product 
        JOIN performance ON performance.ProductID = product.ProductID
        JOIN plan ON performance.PlanID = plan.PlanID
GROUP BY product.ProductName
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What does a query like this result in?

```
SELECT product.ProductName as Name, plan.Status as Status, 
    performance.Capacity as Capacity
FROM product, plan, performance
WHERE performance.PlanID <> plan.PlanID 
    AND performance.ProductID <> product.ProductID
;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am looking for a pivot.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you always use explicit joins.

Updated from your comments:

```
SELECT product.ProductName as Name
     , plan.Status as Status
     , SUM(performance.Capacity) as Capacity
FROM product
INNER JOIN plan
   ON performance.PlanID = plan.PlanID
INNER JOIN performance
   ON performance.ProductID = product.ProductID
GROUP BY product.ProductName
       , plan.Status as Status
```

Comment: Thank you. What I want to pivot is the sum of capacity for the two possible statuses.

Comment: Thank you. What I want to pivot is the sum of capacity for the two possible statuses.

Name        LiveCapacity    PendingCapacity
--------        -----------------    ----------------------
Product1       56                        52
Product2        34                        30

etc.

I am using explicit joins in the FROM (SELECT....) section of my pivot query.

I don't have access to the workspace from the machine I am on this evening, otherwise I would submit my full code. If I had my choice, I would not use a select query for this at all, but my rights are limited in this DB.